# Cannot replace all back slashes with forward one " from \ to /

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

Cannot replace all backslashes with forward ones " from \ to /   .

Tried many combinations but to no avail.

```
var a = 'images\1572714983295\10423479\401891269961412\82824649\n.jpg';

console.log(a.replace(/\//g),"/")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without manipulating the original string, you could do something inline like this:

```js
String.raw`images\1572714983295\10423479\401891269961412\82824649\n.jpg`.replace(/\\/g, "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to escape the backwards slash, like so:

```
"/46\\465531_Thumbnail.jpg".replace(/\\/g,"/")
```

This works and outputs:

```
"/46/465531_Thumbnail.jpg"
```

as expected.

Comment: It didn't work with my string, i executed yours it worked but not mine.

Comment: i need to do it away with single backslash, double backslashes is not a problem